# Statistic calculation (Conversion from one unit to another)

Tags: self-study, arithmetic, units

[image]

I could get the mean using the formulae
but not the value of SD and IQR from using the formulae. What is the problem?

Comment: Yes, what *is* the problem? This question asks you to plug three numbers into the formula.  If you succeeded with one calculation, what prevented you from succeeding with the other two calculations, which are carried out in the same way?

Comment: I have no idea. Can you give me some hint???

Comment: To obtain the answer for the SD, let $F=3$ and compute $C = \frac{5}{9}(F-32) = \frac{5}{9}(3-32)$.  The other two calculations are carried out the same way.

Comment: @whuber: That would give a negative standard deviation.

Comment: @Scortchi You're right--I was not paying any attention to what the numbers mean!  Way too hurried this morning... .  Lim Zhi, because both the SD and the IQR *compare* temperatures, the "$-32$" in the conversion formula is inapplicable: all that matters is that each degree Fahrenheit is $5/9$ degrees Celsius, whence an SD of $3$ degrees F is an SD of $3\times 5/9$ degrees C, and similarly for the IQR.

Answer (score 2):

To convert the standard deviation & inter-quartile range—measuring spread—, it's only the relative size of a degree Fahrenheit & a degree Celsius that's relevant, not the arbitrary zero points of each scale. To convert means, of course the location matters.